# How do I check the progress of Badblocks if it's running in the background?

Tags: fsck

I'm running a drive check on my unmounted USB3 drive with:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -cDfty -C 0 /dev/sda1 &
```

However, I sent it to the background and would like to check its progress. It's been running on a 4 TB drive for 35 hours already.

Is there a way to check its progress?

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you should check whether or not your process is still attached to your terminal.

```
$ ps -eo comm,tty | grep fsck
```

Now, if you can still see a TTY value next to your process, you can still get its output (from this TTY). You can get your current TTY's ID using `tty`. However, if there's a `?` next to your process, I'm afraid you can't get its output anyore (unless you used something like `screen`).

If your process is still attached to a running terminal, you can bring the process back in the foreground using `fg` (in this terminal of course) :

```
$ jobs
$ fg [job ID]
```

`jobs` will give you the ID associated with the running `fsck.ext4` process. Then, use it when calling `fg`. You can also call `fg` without arguments if there's only one job in the background.

I am not familiar with `fsck.ext4` but the `-t` switch you used seems to print statistics (edit: so does the `-C 0` option). By bringing the process back in the foreground, you will get this output back. However, if `fsck.ext4` hasn't been started with verbose options, then it won't print anything, no matter whether it is in the foreground or in the background. In this case, you can just check whether or not it is still running using `ps`.

When you're done, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to send the process in the background again. Be careful though, if your process is attached to the terminal (that is, if the program belongs to the terminal's controlling session), then closing the terminal will send a `SIGHUP` to your process, and kill it (unless you made `fsck.ext4` ignore `SIGHUP`s).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply John Smith! Unfortunately, 'jobs' doesn't actually do anything. I'm on a Raspberry Pi and pretty unfamiliar, but I see what you're getting at process wise.

Comment: If `jobs` prints nothing, then there's no background process in this shell. You probably had an `?` when you checked your process' TTY in the first part of my answer. In this case you won't be able to get your process back into your shell anyway.

Comment: If you used `screen`, wouldn't you see a `pty` here? (Just asking; haven't tried it here.)

Comment: Ctrl-Z doesn't background a process. It stops it, and returns you to the shell. You then have to say `bg` to background it. Until then, it's paused.

Comment: Regarding `SIGHUP`, you can avoid that problem with `disown`, a Bash builtin. (This being Linux, the chances of the OP running Bash are high.)